# JBoss Tools 3.2, Helios (eclipse 3.6.2) - Project Archives shows only JAR option

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I've installed a fresh copy of "eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32.zip" on a 32 bit win 7 machine.  I'm running Java 6.

Then I installed JBoss Tools from http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/, by pasting the url in Help->Install New Software.  I selected to install everything.

I created a sample "Dynamic Web Project" for testing.

Now when I open the "Project Archives" ( Window > Show View > Other > JBoss Tools > Project archives), select my Dynamic Web Project and right click to create a WAR.

PROBLEM - I only get the JAR option.  No other options like WAR, EAR are seen.

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer here:
http://community.jboss.org/message/630475#630475

> These menu items were removed during work for
> https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-9009
>
> The issue was
> initialization of some core underlying libraries during the
> convenience action. Unfortunately, after lots of investigation, the
> root causes were never discovered and the only solution was to remove
> the actions entirely, or, leave them in and allow some users to have
> broken projects or workspaces throwing errors everywhere.
>
> The decision was made to remove them.
>
> The "workaround", or, the new way
> to do it, is to simply use the .jar archive feature, and build out the
> structure you wish to see.
>
> The convenience actions really were not
> as useful as we would have liked to begin with. Project archives is,
> typically, used for non WTP-style projects. Because of this, we really
> have no way at all to predict how the users project is structured. We
> did some simple guess-and-verify work, but it was often wrong. Users
> often found the guesses counterproductive, as they then had to go
> remove invalid filesets, and add in new ones themselves. Combining
> this with the initialization errors in JBIDE-9009, and it was not a
> difficult decision to remove the conveineice actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking the project on the package explorer and select "Export". There should be a "WAR" option. If not, check if the project's facets are configured correctly (open the project's preferences, search for "Facets". "Dynamic Web Project" should be ticked on the facet list)

Comment: What perspective are you on? The `Export WAR` option will only appear if you are at the `Web` or `Java EE` perspective.

Comment: Paolo - I do get the export option, but thats not what I want. I want to be able to configure a deployable war using "Project Archives", run jboss from within eclipse in debug mode and then do a hot deploy of the configured WAR. But since I dont get an option, i cant do the needed. What if the project is huge and i want to selectively (specific files etc) hot deploy a war file, while debugging within eclipse.

Comment: Did you configure your JBoss server runtime (as in http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.0.0.GA/as/en/html/runtimes_servers.html) ? If yes, open the "Servers" window, right-click on the server you've configure and then "Add/Remove". It lets you select which WARs/EARs/JARs should be deployed to the server when starting it from Eclipse, including on debug mode.

Comment: I can do all that, but that deploys the whole project.  I want to selectively design my WAR file to deploy, instead of putting the whole project from Add/Remove. I could do what i want using an ANT script, but I'm trying to implement it using JBOSS tools "Project Archives" perspective.

Comment: Ah, I finally see that. When you right-click a file/folder on the package explorer, there's a "Mark as deployable" or "Unmark as deployable" operation, but I've never used that. Also, I don't think it would give you the level of control you'd need.

Answer (score 0):

try to re-install the plug-in with the eclipse marketplace,
it's just to drag and drop the "install" icon in eclipse.

This is the plugin : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools-1

And i think if you folow these steps, all the options of this method work successfully.